# Dynamic dropdown selection fills in textfields from db with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have 2 files. html.php and getuser.php

In html.php I have a dynamic dropdown filled with ids from a mysql database.
In getuser.php I have code that should take the selected dropdown value and return the companyname where the id is the same as the id value from the dropdown.

You can see the files in jsfiddle (In the js area!):

```
 html.php
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/qHvZM/1/)

```
 getuser.php
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/Ez9Hs/)

---

WHAT DO I WANT TO ACHIEVE:
The db has the following details:

cb_dealerid = 001, 002, 003, 004

cb_bedrijfsnaam = Joop BV, Kelly Ltd, Johan Ltd, Peter BV

When you select from the dropdown value 002 then it should say in the appropriate area Kelly Ltd.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: jsfiddle is not for PHP code

Comment: I know but you can see the entire page in jsfiddle and it is not deleting any parts of the code. I could copy the entire code in here but that makes the page very long and i have to add spaces in front of it. Which is kind of tedious but thank you for telling me this. Maybe you can also give me an push in the right direction for solving my problem.

Comment: have you read any [tutorials on how to use AJAX](https://www.google.com/search?q=tutorial+on+how+to+use+ajax&oq=tutorial+on+how+to+use+ajax)?

Comment: Yes I did. A lot of them actually today. And the codes I have in those 2 files come from the w3schools tutorial but it aint working. Yes it is working beautiful on their website. But I cant get it to work on my own website. The codes are changed a little bit to fit my needs and to connect to the right db and table. @amaster507 what i want to achieve will take hours to write such a script right?

Comment: so let me get this right and reword the question to clarify. You have a form with a select field that is populated with a database of users and then when a user is selected, you want the company name for that user to appear on the same page without reloading the form. Also the time to write a script varies with experience and knowledge, time could grow exponentially if you do not know how to write any php, javascript. In other words it could take a few minutes, or it could take days/weeks

Comment: Yes that is what i want to achieve there are a lot more items than only the companyname but when the companyname is displayed i can duplicate the code as many times as i need i am good in duplicating very good actually. i guess that for you it is the few minutes for me it is the few weeks rather then days. i can give you all the information you need i can setup a db/site etc if needed. I wont post it on stackoverflow but will send by pm if that is possible otherwise email. thanks for the reply and help.

Comment: ok, so there is more than one way to skin this cat. How many users are there that will be in this select list? If it is a relatively smaller number then there might be an easier way then with full AJAX.

Comment: It should be build for 1000s of users. Right now it is about a hundred but this will be expanding rapidly on the end of the year.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35786/discussion-between-amaster507-and-hennysmafter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have a form with a select field that is populated with a database of users and then when a user is selected, you want the company name for that user to appear on the same page without reloading the form.

html.php:

```
<script>
//AJAX request function
function createRequestObject(){
    var requestObject;
    requestObject = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();
    return requestObject;
}

//AJAX needed var for request object
var http = createRequestObject();

//AJAX check for exsiting value for column in table in the database
function showUser(str){
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    http.open("get","getuser.php?q="+str);//you may need to put in full path to your page such as "http://youdomain.com/getuser.php?q="
    http.onreadystatechange = AJAXresponseAction;
    http.send(null);
}

//AJAX function to run on status change
function AJAXresponseAction(){
    if(http.readyState == 4){
        var response = http.responseText;
        //update element with AJAX response text
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=response;
    }
}
</script>
<?php
// Load Joomla! configuration file
require_once('configuration.php');
// Create a JConfig object
$config = new JConfig();
// Get the required codes from the configuration file
$server = $config->host;
$username   = $config->user;
$password   = $config->password;
$database = $config->db;
// Tools dropdown
$con = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database);
$sql = "SELECT cb_dealerid FROM cypg8_comprofiler";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<form>
    <select name='cb_dealerid' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>
        <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php print $row['cb_dealerid'];?>"><?php print $row['cb_dealerid'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

getuser.php:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
// Load Joomla! configuration file
require_once('configuration.php');
// Create a JConfig object
$config = new JConfig();
// Get the required codes from the configuration file
$server = $config->host;
$username   = $config->user;
$password   = $config->password;
$database = $config->db;

$con = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

//********************************************************************//
// ALWAYS MAKE SURE TO ESCPAE STRINGS WHEN USING VARIABLES IN QUERIES //
//********************************************************************//

$q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$q);

$sql="SELECT * FROM cypg8_comprofiler WHERE cb_dealerid = '".$q."' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//If a table is needed build it on the html page for easier coding.
print $row['cb_dealerbedrijfsnaam'];

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help that you have given me. I wish you all the best!